# Can PCIe bifurcation be dangerous?

Tags: pci-express

If I set the PCIe slot bifurcation to x4x4x4x4 and connect a x16 GPU to it, could this possibly damage the GPU?  I understand it won't work, but I'm wondering if it could cause any permanent damage.

Explanation:
I have a Supermicro X11DPG-QT motherboard.  In an attempt to use an NVMe card, I changed the PCIe slot bifurcation to x4x4x4x4 and now it won't boot.  I can't even connect via IPMI, which should typically work even with no GPU.  I suspect I may have changed the wrong slot, since this is not labeled well in the BIOS.

Comment: Enabling bifurcation would not cause hardware damage.  This NVMe card was functional before you enabled bifurcation?  If you disable bifurcation on all slots does the card still not work?

Comment: This card definitely requires bifurcation. It's brand new so this was the first test. I have to wait for physical access to reset the CMOS now

Answer (score 0):

Bifurcation is just a standard for linking the lanes. There is absolutely no danger for the device or motherboard.

Bifurcation usually works on all lanes, that are directly connected to the CPU or also on some higher end chipsets with advanced driver support. Usually Asrock is known for working and at work we use ASUS boards. Hard, to find information on compatible Motherboards.

However: You can in theory connect PCIe Gen1-4 with 1,2,4,8 and 16 lanes. It does not matter, if the Motherboard or the device is lower in any of those spec. The link always is formed by the lowest link in the chain. But usually absolutely every combination should work, if bifurcation is supported. There are even chips, that can assign 64 lanes! PCIe allows almost everything, though chips are hardly available just like proper documentation.

Only dangers, that can occour are, if you pull to much current through anything or make a mistake and short anything - or of course ESD discharge.